# DB2 vs MS-SQL data filter

Tags: sql-server, db2, db2-400

I'm doing a data migration from DB2 to MS-SQL.
And I came across this issue.

Whenever I select records like REGN20 > '3' from DB2 side, I get the following result:

[image]

whereas if I do the same selection from the MS-SQL side, I get the following:

[image]

REGNO (char 2)

How can I get the result set as per DB2 from the MS-SQL side?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Also add information about platform (DB2 for LUW / IBM i / z/OS) and version of DB2. This seems to be a problem of character set differences (EBCDIC/ASCII) and collation.

Comment: DB2 is from a System 21 on IBM AS400

Answer (score 0):

AS400 is an EBCDIC platform. SQL Server runs on ASCII platforms
I EBCDIC, number are at the end of the character table (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) while in ASCII they precede letters.

So when two char values are compared the result differs with the charset

You can use the [COLLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver16) clause to use a [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/sql-server-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that fits EBCDIC code CCSID

You can obtain the CCSID on the IBM i using `select current_numeric_value from qsys2.SYSTEM_VALUE_INFO where system_value_name = 'QCCSID'`

Example :

```
create table t1 (c char(1));
```

```
insert into t1 values ('1'), ('A');
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
select * from t1 order by c;
```

| c |
| --- |
| 1 |
| A |

```
select * from t1 order by c collate SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS;
```

| c |
| --- |
| A |
| 1 |

```
select * from t1 where c >= '1'
```

| c |
| --- |
| 1 |
| A |

```
select * from t1 where c >= '1' collate SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS;
```

| c |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ncGtO2GK)